# ¿Cómo puedo juntar tres líneas en una?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Con el siguiente comando, consigo detectar los dispositivos que se conectan a la red. Este comando se queda en escucha en el sistema por lo que continuamente está esperando que aparezcan resultados.

```
tcpdump -lni eth0 -vvv -s 1500 '((udp port 67) and (udp[247:4] = 0x63350103))' | grep --line-buffered -E -i 'client-id|requested-ip|hostname' | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Una vez alguien se conecte a la red, el resultado es el siguiente. 3 lineas que muestran la MAC, IP y Hostname en este orden. Como ejemplo:

```
98:9f:62:51:9d:2e
10.0.2.11
iPhone
```

Si se vuelve a conectar alguien, me aparecerán 3 lineas mas y así sucesivamente.

Me gustaría poder presentar los 3 resultados por conexión en una única de la siguiente forma:

```
98:9f:62:51:9d:2e 10.0.2.11 iPhone
```

¿Hay forma de poder controlar esta salida?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si tu problema se limita a tener que imprimir de a 3 líneas por vez, se me ocurre que podrías resolverlo desde el script `awk` así:

```
awk '{printf (NR%3==0) ? $0 "\n" : $0" "}'
```

Básicamente vamos imprimiendo con `printf` (que no agrega salto de línea) y en caso el número de línea sea múltiplo de 3 `(NR%3==0)` agregamos el `\n`.

Comment: ¡Muy buena respuesta! Puedes simplificar con un `awk '{printf (NR%3) ? $0 " " : $0"\n"}'`, pues `NR%3 == 0` no es tan necesario y puede utilizarse su resultado implícitamente

Answer (score 4):

Está muy bien [la solución que sugiere Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/312142/83), es una forma muy interesante de utilizar `NR`.

Le podemos dar una vuelta con algo incluso más idiomático:

```
awk 'ORS=(NR%3) ? FS : RS'
```

¿Cómo funciona?

- `RS` es el separador de registros.
- `ORS` es el separador de registros al imprimirlos.
- `NR` es el número de registro.
- `FS` es el separador de campos de un registro.

Por defecto, RS y ORS son "\n" y FS es el espacio. Por eso, podemos hacer esta *jugarreta*: si el número de registro no es múltiplo de 3, utiliza como ORS el espacio. En caso contrario (es decir, en las líneas múltiples de 3) utiliza RS.
A efectos prácticos: si la línea es múltiple de 3, imprime normalmente. Si no, imprime seguida de un espacio.

Puedes leer muchos truquillos de estos en [Idiomatic awk](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) <sub>en inglés</sub>.

---

Incluso más fácil es con `xargs`:

```
xargs -n 3
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs -n 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10
```

Lo que hace `xargs` es coger los argumentos que vienen del pipe. Al decirle `-n 3` lo que hace es cogerlos de 3 en 3.